# How to get the previous and next month?

Tags: php, date

```
$year  = 2010;
$month = 10;
```

How do I get the previous month `2010-09` and next month `2010-11`?

Comment: Could you please explain further!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$date = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year );
echo strftime( '%B %Y', strtotime( '+1 month', $date ) );
echo strftime( '%B %Y', strtotime( '-1 month', $date ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

try it like this:

```
$date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
echo date("Y-m", strtotime('-1 month', $date));
echo date("Y-m", strtotime('+1 month', $date));
```

or, shorter, like this:

```
echo date("Y-m", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month-1, 1, $year));
echo date("Y-m", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month+1, 1, $year));
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is awesome in this respect, it will handle date overflows by correcting the date for you...

```
$PreviousMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month - 1, 1, $year);
$CurrentMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
$NextMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month + 1, 1, $year);

echo '<p>Next month is ' . date('Ym', $NextMonth) . 
    ' and previous month is ' . date('Ym', $PreviousMonth . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$prevMonth = $month - 1;
$nextMonth = $month + 1;
$prevYear = $year;
$nextYear = $year;

if ($prevMonth < 1) {
    $prevMonth = 1;
    $prevYear -= 1;
}

if ($nextMonth > 12) {
    $nextMonth = 1;
    $nextYear += 1
}
```

or

```
// PHP > 5.2.0
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate($year, $month, 1);
$prevDate = $date->modify('-1 month');
$nextDate = $date->modify('+1 month');
// some $prevDate->format() and $nextDate->format()
```

Comment: @RS - I have no trouble with your 5.2 example... it's the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `1` to the current month and then see if you crossed the year:

```
$next_year  = $year;
$next_month = ++$month;

if($next_month == 13) {
  $next_month = 1;    
  $next_year++;
}
```

Similarly for previous month you can do:

```
$prev_year  = $year;
$prev_month = --$month;

if($prev_month == 0) {
  $prev_month = 12;
  $prev_year--;
}
```

Comment: Crikey! Did you know that PHP can do this for you?

Answer (score 0):

***strftime*** **:-** Format the time and/or date according to locale settings. Month and weekday names and other language-dependent strings respect the current locale set with setlocale().

```
strftime( '%B %Y', strtotime( '+1 month', $date ) );
strftime( '%B %Y', strtotime( '-1 month', $date ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next month'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 setlocale(LC_TIME,"turkish");
 $Currentmonth=iconv("ISO-8859-9","UTF-8",strftime('%B'));
 $Previousmonth=iconv("ISO-8859-9","UTF-8",strftime('%B',strtotime('-1 MONTH')));
 $Nextmonth=iconv("ISO-8859-9","UTF-8",strftime('%B',strtotime('+1 MONTH')));

echo $Previousmonth; // Şubat /* 2017-02 */
echo $Currentmonth; // Mart /* 2017-03 */
echo $Nextmonth; // Nisan /* 2017-04 */
```